# Pycrypto on RHEL Fails

Tags: pycrypto

I am trying to install pycrypto via pip. The installation fails with:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-zWtfwz/pycrypto/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-OrjLDy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-zWtfwz/pycrypto/
```

I have found other posts that say I need to download pycrypto via yum, however, the package referenced doesn't seem to exist anymore - at least not by that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yum install gcc*
```

Then run

```
pip install pycrypto
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem, for anyone who may find this in the future.

Further up in the log, I noticed:

> configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Per https://www.thelinuxfaq.com/74-error-no-acceptable-c-compiler-found-in-path-linux

I executed:

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools"
```

and then

```
pip install pycrypto
```

Worked as expected.

> Collecting pycrypto
>     Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz
>   Building wheels for collected packages: pycrypto
>     Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pycrypto ... done
>     Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/80/1f/94/f76e9746864f198eb0e304aeec319159fa41b082f61281ffce
>   Successfully built pycrypto
>   Installing collected packages: pycrypto
>   **Successfully installed pycrypto-2.6.1**